# Displaying contact name when a pin is clicked on the mapview

Tags: iphone, mapkit, addressbook, mkpinannotationview

I'm using the MapKit framework and I have used pins to display the exact address location of the contacts in my addressbook. Till now everything is working fine. But when i click on a pin I need to show the name of the contact, that particular pin represents. Right now I cant figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the "title" and "subtitle" members of an MKAnnotation should do the job.

You can take a look at the [MKMapView sample for Speedy](http://www.speedyapi.com/index.php/ios-samples) I just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Search on google : Subclass MKPinAnnotation